# working on sharepint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a sharepoint project .I insatalled a sharepoint on my computer .I want to create list on my computer and then deploy to customer enviroment.
My customer didn't give me any remote desktop connetion to me and I should go to customer office for creating list and implement sharepoint.
I want a way to work offline,working on my sharepoint server and then transfer to customer server.
A way like site template.But site template has a problem , if I create a site from a site template I can't change it and deploy another another template.
Any Idea?

Comment: The best way is to build up WSP with features for the customization you are doing.. than on customer end, deploy WSP, and enable features to implement the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your list with code in Visual Studio. Test it in your sever. When you finish get a WSP package from your Visual Studio solution. Then you can bring it to client server and install IT with stsadm. In the same way you create and install other kind solutions, like workflows, event receivers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom SharePoint List using visual studio and you can deploy the same code in your client environment. Check this link to know how to create SharePoint List using visual studio.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412429/SharePoint-Create-List-Definition-and-Instanc